# . htaccess for disable directory listing

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I have my php  files of web page  on a remote Linux server.I have my files and sub directories in a directory called xyz eg:**www.servername/xyz/page1.php** if I remove **page1.php** it will list all the files I want to disable it.I don't know where **.htaccess** file is present I have only access to xyz folder.Apache2.25  server I am using.

I created **.htaccess** file in notepad added  `IndexIgnore *` and saved file in xyz folder still not working please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend that you contact the system admin to tell them to turn off directory listing globally in Apache. The default should be off and rather only turn it on if it's explicitly needed. If you can't do that, try this in your htaccess instead: `Options -Indexes`. Also make sure that there's a new line after it (press enter). Sometimes Apache can be really picky.

Answer (score 1):

save your  .htaccess file in your xyz directory (check if previous one is hidden or not, most hosting provider hide all files starting with . dot )

if you want to turn off directory list (auto-indexing), i'll suggest you to use  :

```
Options -Indexes
```

and if you don't want some things to show up in an auto-index, then use

```
IndexIgnore
```